# regexp - match multiple variations of datestamp

Tags: php, regex

I need to match multiple variations of a datestamp

```
$test = array(
    '01-05-2011',
    '01-05-11',
    '01.12.2012',
    '30042016'
);

$date_day_pattern = '01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31';
$date_year_pattern = '(?:20)?10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30';

$date_pattern = "(?<!\d)($date_day_pattern)[^\d\n]?($date_day_pattern)[^\d\n]?($date_year_pattern)(?!\d)";
foreach($test as $input){
    preg_match("/$date_pattern/", $input, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

http://www.tehplayground.com/#R1sjJxFho

Comment: Just from 2010-2030 or would be 2029/2039 okay as well? Are leading zeros necessary or optional? What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: What is the problem with above code?

Comment: it doesn't match day month year

Comment: Don't do this with regex. Convert each string to a timestamp via `strtotime()` or `new DateTime()` and then compare the converted values.

Comment: the output comes from OCR so the input string is not just the datestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shortened regex should work for your examples:

```
$test = array(
    '01-05-2011',
    '01-05-11',
    '01.12.2012',
    '30042016'
);

$date_pattern =
   '/\b(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([.-]?)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2((?:20)?(?:[12][0-9]|30))\b/';

foreach($test as $input){
   echo $input."\n";
   preg_match($date_pattern, $input, $matches); print_r($matches);
}
```

Though you should consider using date parsing functions such as `strtotime` for proper date validations and parsing.

**Output:**

```
01-05-2011
Array
(
    [0] => 01-05-2011
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 05
    [3] => 2011
)
01-05-11
Array
(
    [0] => 01-05-11
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 05
    [3] => 11
)
01.12.2012
Array
(
    [0] => 01.12.2012
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 2012
)
30042016
Array
(
    [0] => 30042016
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 04
    [3] => 2016
)
```

Comment: Your code allows mixtures of dots/no dots, therefore a data like 10.102012 would match. And the date format is wrong since '-' require 'Month-day' while dots require 'Day.Month'.

Comment: ok it is updated to disallow mix of hyphen/dots/no dots. However as I suggested real date parsing routines are the way to go otherwise it will also validate 31-02-2017` as valid date.

Comment: @RafaelAlbert it doesn't matter.. The haystack comes from OCR so the seperator char could be anything.. even a misinterpreted char

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Comment: @clarkk: In that case you may consider `'/\b(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\W?)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2((?:20)?(?:[12][0-9]|30))\b/'` also

Answer (score 1):

I have written a pattern that should work. It looks slightly different than yours, but matches every case you have described there and fails in any other case.

```
'(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])-(?:20)?(?:[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[[01]])(\.?)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\1)20(?:[1-2][0-9]|30))'
```

**Explanation**: 
I have combined case1&2 and case3&4 and have written a pattern for each of those and merged them together with a logical or. The code is pretty straightforward, the only noteworthy thing is the backreference in the second part that is used to allow two dots/no dots and not a mixture.